# IIS issue with CSS (asp.NET)

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

For some reason when I deploy my app on IIS sever the menu item appears to be ignoring or picking up incorrect css.

This is the html when deployed to IIS6

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>

</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

and this is on localhost

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>

</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css"> 
    .ctl00_NavigationMenu_0 { background-color:white;visibility:hidden;display:none;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px; }
    .ctl00_NavigationMenu_1 { text-decoration:none; }
    .ctl00_NavigationMenu_2 {  }
    .ctl00_NavigationMenu_3 { border-style:none; }
    .ctl00_NavigationMenu_4 {  }

</style></head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUIMTgxOTUzNzlkZCNjjPhsCt06uFnsECs0BUpSQWBv" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Any ideas why this is causing an issue when deployed? Site is using a master page and forms authentication although the title and otehr layout features are working fine from the css sheet.

Note, I have just moved from apache web server to iis and was working fine on Apache.

Any help much appreciated.

This is the code from master page, anything obvious here?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="FoundryStatusReport.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1 style="font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none;">
                    Report <br />
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx"/>  ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>

            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                    EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="MenuItemCSS">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" />

                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>

            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Red" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">London Checks</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#006600" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/HKG_Exotics.aspx">Asia Checks</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What injects that menu css?  If it's just embedded in the master, then I'd say that you didn't actually deploy the master page.  Go look at the file on the server itself to see if it contains your code.

Comment: Yes my site.master is deployed. I notice that the header etc from the master page also looks ok. Also the items on the menu are present just have lost styling.

Im not sure where the .ct100 has come from. Has enabling forms authentication caused some kind of block on this do you think?

Comment: What is the hierarchy of default.aspx page and associated css, can you send the folder structure?

Comment: OK, I have removed authentication now so this is not the issue...


So I have my Default.aspx in root folder with site.master. Site.CSS is in a Style subfolder.

Comment: I dont understand why this has started being an issue on new webserver. Is there an IIS setting that could affect this?

Comment: With your master page code I don't see that you actually have any style tags or css classes in it.  Which leads me back to: What is injecting the css into your page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this actually ended up being due to a different ASP.NET version specified in the webserver. Specified version was 4 instead of 2.x.

See http://abhijitjana.net/2010/05/18/css-friendly-menu-control-in-asp-net-4-0/

Thanks all